# Building resources into a DLL for reuse, MFC/VC++

Tags: visual-c++, dll, resources

For example, I want to build a DLL exporting a function called ShowDialog, which displays a dialog and changes the text in one of the dialog buttons. The dialog and all other resources should be bundled in the DLL.

I did a quick test and when the DLL tries GetDlgItem() with a certain control ID, it gets a null pointer back. I'm assuming more steps are required to handle the resources properly in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9d5yh5(VS.80).aspx):

> By default, MFC uses the resource
>   handle of the main application to load
>   the resource template. If you have an
>   exported function in a DLL, such as
>   one that launches a dialog box in the
>   DLL, this template is actually stored
>   in the DLL module. You need to switch
>   the module state for the correct
>   handle to be used. You can do this by
>   adding the following code to the
>   beginning of the function:

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you do something like the following at the entry points to your DLL?

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ))
```

Check this [technote here about MFC module state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx). There are various types of MFC module state, module state is the one you most commonly interact with.

> This swaps the current module state
>   with the state returned from
>   AfxGetStaticModuleState until the end
>   of the current scope.
>
> Problems with resources in DLLs will
>   occur if the AFX_MODULE_STATE macro is
>   not used. By default, MFC uses the
>   resource handle of the main
>   application to load the resource
>   template. This template is actually
>   stored in the DLL. The root cause is
>   that MFC's module state information
>   has not been switched by the
>   AFX_MODULE_STATE macro. The resource
>   handle is recovered from MFC's module
>   state. Not switching the module state
>   causes the wrong resource handle to be
>   used.

Comment: Thanks. Even though this reply carries more info I selected the other one to be the correct answer, since calling AFX_MANAGE_STATE at the entry point of the DLL doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it does. The entry points to the DLL are any point that external code can call into your module. I presume you thought I meant something like in DLLMain or some such place

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for the misunderstanding.